# Excel - Conditional formatting and field name look up

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, lookup

What I need to do is find which cell in a row is the lowest value and highlight it. Very simple, I can do this. However, I cannot figure uot how to copy this conditional formatting into the proceeding rows. I have tried "Paste Special > Formats" to no avail.

Also, in a separate column, I to display the field name9column name) of the specific cell that has been returned with the lowest value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I see two questions:

First, how to copy conditional formatting. Simply select the formatted data, click the "Format Painter" tool on the Home tab, and select the additional data you wish to format.

Second, how to display the cell with the lowest value.

<strike>Use the `MIN` function to do this. If your range is A1:A100, use `=MIN(A1:A100)`</strike>

Use the following: `=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(MIN(A2:E2),A2:E2,0))`

A1:E1 is the range containing your column names. A2:E2 is the row with your values. Note that if the values are not unique, this will return the first instance of the minimum value, starting from the left.

Comment: Thank you for the first answer. The second question was how to display the column name of that cell. That is, is cell A5 is determined to have the lowest value, I need to find its column name. I can do this if I could find a way to return the location of the cell, in contrast to its actual value as done with MIN()

Comment: I see that I misread your second question. What you want is a bit more complex. Are the values unique, or would it be possible to have a row with values like `2 3 3 4 2`?

Comment: The values are not unique actually. I was thinking something on the lines of this:

Comment: =OFFSET(ADDRESSofMINcell, -(ROW(ADDRESSofMINcell)-1), 0)

Comment: I edited my answer. What is your preferred behavior in cases where the minimum value appears multiple times?

Comment: Perhaps if there are two, or more, with the same minimum value I would like it to display the first returned value's column name followed by an astrerisk *

Comment: In that case, use `=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(MIN(A2:E2),A2:E2,0))&IF(COUNTIF(A2:E2,MIN(A2:E2))>1,"*","")`